# Lightroom TIFF XMP sidecar missing?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, tiff, xmp, sidecar

Before asking my question I'll quickly describe my workflow when shooting stock photos:

1. **Import CR2** in LR
2. **Basic edits** (exposure, sharpness), LR writes changes in **sidecar XMP**
3. Send JPGs to client who makes selection
4. Flag picked photos in LR
5. **open in PS (TIFF)**
6. Isolate product (vector mask)
7. **Open TIFF in LR**
8. Finer edits (exposure, simple spot removal)

**I am wondering where the edits in the last step are stored.**
For the isolated TIFF that has been edited in LR again, 
a sidecar XMP can nowhere be found.

Also I'm completely open for any comments or critique to my workflow! I'm here to learn.

> "Metadata that is stored in other formats, such as EXIF, IPTC (IIM),
>   and TIFF, is synchronized and described with XMP so that it can be
>   more easily viewed and managed."
>   via http://help.adobe.com/en_US/lightroom/using/WS638E3AC9-A04C-4445-A0D3-F7D8BA5CDE37.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your step 5., when you export a RAW file from LR to PS (or when you open a RAW file with PS, make some editing and then save it in TIFF format and import it back to LR), a TIFF get created. However, this TIFF has no sidecar file attached, so you won't find any.

So back in LR **with a TIFF file, you expect the changes you made to be saved in a XMP file... but no, LR nor PS won't do it : XMP files are only used when associated to *proprietary RAW* files.**

**When using DNG or TIFF file, the change are stored in the file itself** (and very probably in the LR/PS Catalog but I haven't checked).

From the same link you provided (for LR 4), you can read (**[...]** are my editions):

> In the case of camera raw files that have a proprietary file format,
>   XMP isn’t written into the original files. To avoid file corruption,
>   XMP metadata is stored in a separate file called a sidecar file. For
>   all other file formats supported by Lightroom (JPEG, TIFF, PSD, and
>   DNG), XMP metadata is written into the files **[not the XMP sidecar file]** in the location specified **[=the file itself and/or the catalog]**
>   for that data

You can check it by opening your TIFF file with a text editor. Probably 5 lines after some unreadable binary data, you will find a readable part => that's the XMP part. It starts by `<x:xmpmeta [...] >` and finishes by `</x:xmpmeta>`. As you can see, it's completely readable and the exact copy of what you would find in a sidecar file, if it existed.

A more "modern" source, ["Photoshop CC for Photographers"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1138812471) indicates the same thing in the "Camera Raw preferences" part : no XMP sidecar for TIFF file.

Remember that one of the goal of XMP files is to provide a mean to export editing information from one computer to an other. For undocumented / rapidly changing / proprietary format, it makes sense. However, TIFF and DNG format are public, stable and well documented formats, so stocking XMP information in the file itself is perfectly fine.